# Ajax show only in inspect element -> network

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Have a problem with a ajax. I search and can not find an answer.

My problem is that I have a code:

```
function generateNewNumber() {
  $("#_res_number").html('');
  $.ajax({
      url: './content/ajax/generate_number.php?_unique=<?php echo $unique; ?>',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
         $("#_res_number").html(data+['number']);
      }
  });
}
```

I can see a result only in inspect element-> network in my browser. But the div is not a change.

Div :

```
<div id="_res_number" style="height: 30px;"></div>
```

have anyone an idea why?

Comment: `data+['number']` what is this plus sign doing here? Also it helps if you post the content of the returned json.

Comment: Thank you for fast response, plus is removed but problem still persist :(

Answer (score 0):

just pass your data like this

```
$("#_res_number").html(data['number']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response is a json object; try something like

```
function generateNewNumber() {
  $("#_res_number").html('');
  $.ajax({
      url: './content/ajax/generate_number.php?_unique=<?php echo $unique; ?>',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {

         data = JSON.parse(data);

         $("#_res_number").html(data.number);
      }
  });
}
```

If this doesn't work; please post the response from the ajax request so I can help you more.

Comment: Thank you for fast response. Are you talking about change dataType:
 'json' to data = JSON.parse(data); ? The respone from inspect element > network is : {"confirmed":"23.30"}

Comment: OK so instead of number, you need to use result as this is what you need to update the div with. So your success part becomes: data = JSON.parse(data); $("#_res_number").html(data.result);

Comment: Sorry that was mistake and I send a bad response {"confirmed":"23.30"}

Comment: You keep changing what your response is! Basically you need to use data.whateverthekeyis

Comment: The problem still persist. Anyway thank you for your time

Comment: I updated my answer to show you where to put that extra line. If your response is a string; you will need to parse it to make into a json object, which will allow you to access the values. Make sure you are trying to use the correct key and if it doesn't work; put the line in to parse the result into an object and then it should work.